# Spring Security Log Out Exception

Tags: spring-security

When I configure Spring Security 3 to log out the user I get a huge error

> Exception in thread ""http-bio-8080"-exec-7" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at com.dc.api.model.Users.getUsername(Users.java:200)

The `Users.java:200` maps to the `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` implementation method

```
public String getUsername() {
    return this.getUsername();
}
```

log out link:

```
<a href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/j_spring_security_logout.html">
log out</a>
```

spring security config:

```
 <logout invalidate-session="true" 
          logout-success-url="/" 
          logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout.html"/>
```

`web.xml`:

I've configured the `springSecurityFilterChain` to run on any forward or request to `*.html` and `*.xhtml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here was the below method thats called by spring security was calling itself and was in an infinite loop.  It should be calling my User model object's userId (`this.getUserId`)

```
public String getUsername() {
    return this.getUsername();
}
```